# Search for registry key path

Tags: cmd, registry

please, could you help me with searching for registry path?

I am trying to find path of `REG_BINARY` with name `00036601` in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\20424cec73cea54ab3d011f91bf036b2`

I have problem because last folder(`20424cec73cea54ab3d011f91bf036b2`) in path is different on every laptop. Cannot find any working solution with REG QUERY in cmd or powershell.

I know how to find it in known path or list all subkeys, but failed to filter one value.

So i want to get output like: key name `00036601` found in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\Outlook\20424cec73cea54ab3d011f91bf036b2`

EDIT: sorry for my english, maybe i am notz describing it correctly, please, could you look on image?

[Regedit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG5ae.jpg)

I am looking for string name 00036601 - marked in image. Thanks for help

EDIT2: i found way how to do it with cmd "REG QUERY HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft /s /f 00036601"

But not with powershell...

Answer (score 0):

You can search the registry with PowerShell. I do not have the same registry path as you have.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path  HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0 `
    -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
    Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq '00036601' }
```

If you must do it from a cmd.exe shell:

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile ^
   "Get-ChildItem -Path HKCU: -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | " ^
    "Where-Object { $_.PSChildName -eq '00036601' }"
```

**EDIT:** that was never going to get there.

This works on my machine to find the IM enabled setting.

```
$r = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:/Software/Microsoft/Office/' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { $_.Property -eq 'EnablePresence' }
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $r.PSPath).EnablePresence
```

Please try this on your machine.

```
$r = Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:/Software/Microsoft/Office/' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { $_.Property -eq '00036601' }
(Get-ItemProperty -Path $r.PSPath).'00036601'
```

Comment: Thank you,  this can return path of key based on search of key name(folder), but how to return path of key based on search of reg_sz string name? I cannot search with key name, because its different on every laptop.

Comment: I thought that `0036601` was the key name for which you were searching. Is that not correct?

Comment: Edited question. Please, look on image. Thanks

Comment: @JakubZoubek - Please have a look at the revised answer.

Comment: Thank you again, when i use just "Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:/Software/Microsoft/Office/' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { $_.Property -eq '00036601' }" it prints all with paths, but i dont have any output when i put it into $r and use last command (Get-ItemProperty -Path $r.PSPath).00036601. But i can filter this output with java, so its good.

Comment: @JakubZoubek - I added apostrophes on the numeric key name at the last line. That may work better for you.

Comment: Interesting, from this "Get-ChildItem -Path 'HKCU:/Software/Microsoft/Office/' -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { $_.Property -eq '00036601' }" i am getting [link](http://textuploader.com/dx3q4) and from your last code i am getting [link](http://textuploader.com/dx3qc)

Comment: @JakubZoubek - I do not have your registry entries. I am not sure I can go any further.